# How to save the values of checkbox to the register setting?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

```
<?php 
function default_menu() {
<form action="options.php" method="post">
 <?php settings_fields( 'sample_check' );?>
<input type="checkbox" name="sample" value="nofollow"/>
</form>


function reg_setting() {
register_setting('sample_check','???');
}
```

Hi all, I have struggled all day to store the check box values to the register setting. For the text box I used:

```
<input type="text" name="sam" value="<?php get_option('samip');?>" />
```

Also I register the values to the register setting like:

```
register_setting('sample_check','samip');
```

But I don't know how to do this for a checkbox. If anyone could give me a suggestion for how to do this, that would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 1):

The settings framework can't detect data that is not posted, so either use a call to update_option or (what I sometimes do) use a yes/no radio button rather than a checkbox. With a radio button where the default value is 0 (no) and the alternative is 1 (yes), the user is setting the post value either way. You're just making the user make an explicit choice.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply put checkbox value it in an option instead :

```
<?php update_option( $option, $new_value ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the the option frameworks

> https://github.com/mb2o/WordPress-Theme-Options-Page
>
> https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-plugin
>
> https://gist.github.com/justinwhall/1997756
>
> https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/4653358
>
> https://gist.github.com/mfields/4678999